# when i install TFS 2013, do I get a full blown sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, tfs

I've been looking around TFS 2013 screenshots and I notice how it look like it's implemented over Sharepoint 2013...
So, when i install TFS 2013, do I get a full blown sharepoint (with central admin and everything), just a site collection (a "light" version of it) or none (meaning if, i want a web interface, i have point to my sharepoint and say "use that one")???

PS: Since i'm in a corporate environment i don't have a spare machine to just install it and check it for myself, and other documentation don't make this clear...

Answer (score 2):

TFS has its own web-based interface (TFS Web Access) that isn't based on SharePoint.  It also has the ability to integrate with SharePoint which will cause SP-based Project Portals to be created with every Team Project (this is in addition to TFS Web Access).

When you install TFS you can choose to have the TFS Install install/configure SharePoint Foundation, or you can point it to a pre-existing SP Foundation or Enterprise environment.

Answer (score 1):

**SharePoint Foundation 2013** can be installed with TFS, if you specify that in the installation.

**Reference**
[SharePoint Products requirements for Team Foundation Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh667648.aspx)